# Deleting LocalNotifications from NotificationCenter (iOS 6)

Tags: iphone, ios6, uilocalnotification

I have a problem with one aspect of managing LocalNotifications - deleting single notification in iOS 6.

[image]

I am able to create a LocalNotification with text content and fire date and it works.

On iOS 5 notification occurs as an AlertView on home screen with two buttons, and dissapears after touching either. I can cancel the fire of notification using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification]`. There is no problem here.

In iOS 6 notification occurs in a Notificaton Center as shown above when fired. If I cancel it using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification]`, it won't fire - it works. But after it fires...

**My problem:**

I am not able to erase this single fired notification from the Notification Center. For example, I would like the notification to dissappear after it is touched, or after some action inside application is done.

**What I tried:**

- using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification]` - cancels notification fire (actually there's no need since the notification **did** fire already), but doesn't erase fired notification from Notification Center
- removing items from `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` array - doesn't work, because this function always returns empty array, no matter how many (working!) notifications are set (does anybody know why?)

**What I'm doing now**

I am deleting all notifications using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]` - it cancels them AND erases from Notification Center, and then create them back, without the one I wanted to erase.

As you can see, this is rather idiotic and redundant solution, but I couldn't find better so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @deleteme. I take time dealing with this problem. Reading your question a realize that why i get an empty array when i call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]`. I guess I´ll use your solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.....May be this help...Write this code from where you want to clear all your notifications.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

To erase one single notification

You can get an array of scheduled notification from: `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *scheduledLocalNotifications`

Get the one you want by the index number of your choosing and then pass the UILocalNotification* to  `- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification.`

You can save a unique value for key in your local notification's userinfo.
Get all local notification, loop through the array and delete the particular notification.

Code as follows,

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
    NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
    {
        //Cancelling local notification
        [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to erase all notifications (I am sure I pointed it out). My aim is to erase one single specific notification.

Comment: I tried this solution already. As 've written in my question, cancelLocalNotification:notification cancels notification fire, but doesn't remove notification from Notification Center

Comment: @femina:can we remove push notification ?